# Ordering in many-to-many relation (Java Spring)

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is 2 models with relation many-to-many:

```
@Entity
public class Map {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @JsonIgnore
  private long mapId;

  @NotBlank
  private String title;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "route_points",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mapId", referencedColumnName = "mapId"),
             inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pointId", referencedColumnName = "pointId"))
  private Set<Point> points;
}

@Entity
public class Point {
  @Id
  private String pointId;
  @NotBlank
  private String city;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "points")
  private Set<Map> maps;
}
```

I have to save an order of points in the set and record it to the intermediate table. How it can be done? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List` instead of a `Set` in combination with the `@OrderColumn` annotation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

This will create an additional column in `route_points` to track the order of elements, including insertion, deletion, and reordering.

Please note that JPA will maintain the ordering as consecutive numbers, so most (if not all) structural modifications to the list will result in an update statement for each and every element.

Answer (score -1):

`Set` basicly does not hold order of insertion. `LinkedHashSet` however will keep order of insertion of elements you could try that. It will store `Point` into database in proper order, but most probably it again will be mixed up after fetching from the database. You have to viable options here:

1. Dont use `Set` use `List` insteed.
2. Stick with `Set` and add `private Integer index` field to `Point`and store proper indexes - you will be able to sort that after fetch without any problems

If you ensure that points will be persisted in right order into databse, then you could ommit additional column and sort by `id` assuming you are using unique, no gaps, autogenerated sequence for PKs

Comment: 'If you ensure that points will be persisted in right order into databse, then you could ommit additional column and sort by id' - no, not really. You seem to assume the OP will never insert a new `Point` in the middle of the list once `Map` has been created. Also, the order of insertion is an implementation detail, and I don't think it is warranted by the JPA spec